# How to listen when a pane comes to front in StackPane (JavaFX)?

Tags: events, javafx, rendering, listener, stackpanel

So here is my problem. In JavaFX, I have created a StackPane and I added various other panes in it. There result is as shown on the picture below. When I click on the buttons below the corresponding Pane appears by use the "toFront()" method. I would like to create listeners on all Panes that will fire whenever they come up to front.
I have tried to use the

```
pane.sceneProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {});
```

but is not working in my case, as the panes are already children of the StackPane, hence already in the scene.

What I am trying to achieve here is to listen whenever a pane/node is actually rendered in the scene. As far as I understand, panes in the stackpane that are behind the front pane are not rendered.

Regards,
Johny

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand, panes in the stackpane that are behind the front pane are not rendered.

This is not quite true. Panes in the stackpane are rendered in a z-order corresponding to their position in the children list; in other words they are rendered one on top of the other, with the first element in the list at the bottom of the stack and the last at the top. If they are all opaque and all fill the entire stack pane, then only the last one will be visible to the user.

You can put together a binding that keeps track of the last item in the stack pane's list (i.e. the node that is at the front) with

```
ObjectBinding<Node> frontLayer = Bindings.valueAt(stack.getChildren(), 
    Bindings.size(stack.getChildren()).subtract(1));
```

SSCCE:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StackPaneReorderTest extends Application {

    private final Random rng = new Random();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).mapToObj(this::createPane).forEach(stack.getChildren()::add);
        Button button = new Button("Change");
        button.setOnAction(e -> 
            stack.getChildren().get(rng.nextInt(stack.getChildren().size() - 1)).toFront());
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(stack, null, null, button, null);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(button, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(button, new Insets(10));

        ObjectBinding<Node> frontLayer = Bindings.valueAt(stack.getChildren(), 
            Bindings.size(stack.getChildren()).subtract(1));
        frontLayer.addListener((obs, oldLayer, newLayer) ->  
            System.out.println(newLayer.getId() + " moved to front"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Pane createPane(int i) {
        Pane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.setId("Layer "+i);
        pane.setStyle(String.format("-fx-background-color: -fx-background; -fx-background: #%x%x%x;", 
            rng.nextInt(16), rng.nextInt(16), rng.nextInt(16)));
        pane.getChildren().add(new Label("Layer "+i));
        return pane ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Note for your particular use case there are probably much better solutions to what you are trying to do. E.g. you could use a `BorderPane` and just call `setCenter` with the node you want to display. Then the `BorderPane`'s `centerProperty` always holds the visible node. There are many other ways to do this.

Comment: Well the thing is that I have been using an AnchorPane before and I was adding and removing Panes into it. But the problem with I experience slow performance issues in rendering, as adding and removing nodes is expensive. However, that was working fine by using sceneProperty() in the pane and catch the event whenever was visible.

Comment: Can u advice an alternative?

Comment: I already did. I can't make it more precise without an example to work from. But what is wrong with the code I posted?

Comment: Hello sorry for the late reply but i am traveling these days and didnt have time to write some code. Well I'll try to be as precise as i Can. A listview can be in a pane, the pane can be in a scrollpane, a scrollpane in a stackpane, that can be in a borderpane etc. i want a kind of a listener so as to when the listview comes in front or rendered in the scene to load the listview with data

Comment: Why not just load the listview with data when you add it to the pane?

Comment: Cause i am using sockets for remote communication with a server. So I want every time that a specific pane becomes visible to send a request and get the data remotely. Plus, there is not only one way that this pane becomes visible. For example you may go through various buttons there or get a request remotely and then the pane becomes visible. For simplicity, what i want is a listener on the pane itself that when it is shown to send request for data and once receive it to load it.

Comment: In the screenshot,let's say u have a stackpane and each time u push a button you load into the stackpane another pane(let'a call it navPane). This navPane it can be used then to load other panes(like for example if a user push a button "more info" another pane is loaded into navPane that shows the more info screen and user can press "back" button to go to previous screen). But all this happens on navPane not on Stackpane. Stackpane only knows that navPane is in front but not what other panes are loaded into navPane. So the listener will not work cause the pane i wanna listen is in the navPane.

Comment: Hope u got the idea, otherwise i'll need to make a drawing here:)

Comment: I guess I don't understand what is wrong with the solution I gave.

Comment: As i am currently away i can't test ur solution, but based on my understanding your listener is not specific to the node that i wanna check if it is rendered but a listener on all children in the stackpane

Comment: You can just check if it is equal to a specific node when it changes.